# Put request to rest api returning 400 bad request

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, strapi

Hello am using strapi rest api and react to create a crud app, I can make a, post, delete and read that from the api endpoint, but I get a 400 bad request when i try to make a PUT request, chrome developer tool says message":"Missing "data" payload in the request body". I'm managing state with Redux-toolkit and querying the API with RTK queries and mutation

petAPi.js

```
  import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

export const petApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'petApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'http://localhost:1337/api' }),
  tagTypes: ['Pet'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPets: builder.query({
      query: () => '/pets',
      providesTags: ['Pet'],
    }),
    getPet: builder.query({
      query: petId => `/pets/${petId}`
    }),
    addNewPet: builder.mutation({
      query: (payload) => ({
        url: '/pets',
        method: 'POST',
        body: payload,
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['Pet'],
    }),
    updatePet: builder.mutation({
      query: (payload) => ({
          url: `/pets/${payload.id}`,
          method: 'PATCH',
          body: payload,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['Pet'],
    }),
    deletePet: builder.mutation({
      query: (id) => ({
        url: `/pets/${id}`,
        method: 'DELETE',
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['Pet'],
    }),
  })
})

export const {
    useGetPetsQuery,
    useGetPetQuery,
    useAddNewPetMutation,
    useUpdatePetMutation,
    useDeletePetMutation,
  } = petApi;
```

EditPetEntry.js

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// mui components
import {
    Typography,
    TextField,
    Box,
    Button,
    Paper
} from '@mui/material';

// mui icons
import { Edit } from '@mui/icons-material';

// custom components
import BottomNav from './BottomNav';

import { useUpdatePetMutation, useGetPetQuery } from '../services/petApi';
import Loader from './Loader';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { usePetContext } from '../petContext';

export default function EditPetEntry() {
    // input data
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [animal, setAnimal] = useState("");
    const [breed, setBreed] = useState("");
    const [age, setAge] = useState("");
    const [location, setLocation] = useState("");
    const [sex, setSex] = useState("");

    // const {petId} = useParams();
    const { petId } = useParams();
    // edit req
    const { data: pet} = useGetPetQuery(petId)
    const [updatePet, { isLoading }] = useUpdatePetMutation();
    const data = JSON.stringify({
        "data": {
            "name": name,
            "animal": animal,
            "breed": breed,
            "age": age,
            "location": location,
            "sex": sex
        }
    });
    const handleEditPet = () => {
        updatePet({ id: petId, pet });
    };

    console.log(data);
    console.log(petId);
    console.log(pet);

    return (
        <Box
            component="form"
            sx={{
                '& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 1, width: '50ch' },
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'column'
            }}
            noValidate
            autoComplete="off"
        >
            <div>
                <Typography variant="h3" gutterBottom component="div">
                    Edit Pet entry
                </Typography>
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="filled-name"
                    label="Name"
                    variant="outlined"
                    onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                />
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="filled-animal"
                    label="Animal"
                    variant="outlined"
                    helperText="Cat, Dog, Bird"
                    onChange={(e) => setAnimal(e.target.value)}
                />
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="filled-breed-input"
                    label="Breed"
                    variant="outlined"
                    onChange={(e) => setBreed(e.target.value)}
                />
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="filled-location-input"
                    label="Location"
                    variant="outlined"
                    onChange={(e) => setLocation(e.target.value)}
                />
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="filled-age"
                    label="Age"
                    type="number"
                    variant="outlined"
                    onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)}
                />
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="sex"
                    label="Sex"
                    helperText="Male, Female"
                    variant="outlined"
                    onChange={(e) => setSex(e.target.value)}
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleEditPet} startIcon={<Edit />}>
                    Edit Pet Entry
                </Button>
                {isLoading && <Loader />}
            </div>
            <Paper sx={{ position: 'fixed', bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0 }} elevation={3}>
                <BottomNav />
            </Paper>
        </Box>
    );
}
```

You can view the rest of the project at [my github page](https://github.com/Keyzcharly/petpound). your help is much appreciated am a new react developer

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the handler with

```js
updatePet(petId, data);
```

But then destructure it with

```js
const { id, ...body } = payload;
```

Maybe call it with

```js
updatePet({ id: petId, ...data });
```

instead.